# Как узнать пересекает ли линия сферу в трёхмерном пространстве

Tags: математика, графика, геометрия, 3d

Подскажите пожалуйста алгоритмы вычисления пересечения сферы отрезком в 3D пространстве. У меня есть вектор начала линии, вектор конца линии. Есть вектор положения сферы и её радиус. Как можно узнать пересекает ли линия сферу?

Comment: под векторами подразумеваются, видимо, просто точки?

Comment: Считаем расстояние от центра сферы до прямой (формула гуглится)

Answer (score 2):

Если расстояния до точек A и B от центра оба меньше радиуса - весь отрезок внутри сферы.

Если одно меньше, второе больше - точно пересекает :)

А вот если оба больше...

Для начала сместим все координаты так, чтоб центр сферы был в начале координат.

Отрезок параметрически задается как

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Расстояния от точек отрезка до начала координат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Простейшая квадратичная функция от t. Ищем минимум. Если минимум достигается при 0<=t<=1, смотрим на его величину и сравниваем с радиусом (точнее, с квадратом радиуса) сферы. Если меньше - все, пересечение есть. Если больше - пересечения нет. Если минимум за искомыми границами [0,1] - пересечения нет.

Как найти минимум от квадратичной функции или скалярно вектора перемножить, надеюсь, знаете...